# Use PHP to "parse" image with response header "content-type: image/jpeg"

Tags: php, image, download

I'm requesting an image from graph.facebook.com

The response header uses "content-type: image/jpeg" and prompts me to download instead of displaying it in the browser.

Is there a way (using PHP) to "intercept" the download and convert it to an image format?

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

This kind of works. It returns the image to the browser (visible in Chrome's Network tab), but I'm not sure how to display it in an `<img>` tag:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/what-does-it-mean-when-cat-wags-tail.jpg");

// $data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $qwe = imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    return $qwe;
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```

Comment: You are downloading a JPEG, but displaying as a PNG?

Comment: @Raptor That was "demo" code. The real (secret) URL was a .png ;)

Answer (score 1):

You code is invalid. You do not use `return` from non function as it makes no sense. If your case you need to replace

```
return $qwe;
```

with just plain

```
echo $qwe;
```

I'd also follow it by instant `die();` and remove closing `?>`. That should be all you need to make it work.

Not sure what is the point of fetching JPEG file but outputting PNG thought. You are gaining nothing but wasting time and resources, so the whole conversion code is pretty useless and echoing what you just downloaded should be perfecly sufficient:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$data = file_get_contents(".....");
if ($data !== false) {
    echo $data;
}
die();
```

PS: As a homework, get rid of using `file_get_contets()` for network access and use cURL, esp. the network wrapper the former uses can be disabled.